# Modeling People/Company Roles

Tags: php, zend-framework, database-design, data-modeling, oop

Ive been working on a project which handles jobs for a home maintenance service, but Im having a difficult time modeling the roles that different people and companies play.  If it matters the system is written using zendFramework, with mySql as the data storage.

Ill do my best to explain but I am not to well versed in the language of data modeling.
the end user of this system is a Maintenance Company I will call **HammerTime** in the following examples. This is what I have so far:

**WorkOrderRequests** come in from two primary sources:
Source 1: **Resident**>>requestWorkOrder>>**PropertyManagementCompany**>>requestWorkOrder>>**HammerTime**

Source 2: **HomeOwner**>>requestWorkOrder>>**HammerTime**

I think of all of these entities as customers, but only **PropertyManagementCompanies** and **HomeOwners** are "direct" customers which will receive invoices.  Also a resident can be a **HomeOwner** if they own the property they reside in. Also to add another layer of business logic on top this, all **Residents** belong to a **Property** and all requests from a **Resident** to a **PropertyManagementCompany** are mediated by a **PropertyManager**

When **WorkOrderRequests** come in to **HammerTime** they are stored as **WorkOrders** and then are handled in a few different ways.

Handled 1: **HammerTime**>>assignWorkOrder>>**Employee**

Handled 2: **HammerTime**>>contractOutWorkOrder>>**ServiceVendor**

I think of these entities as the workers and they seem to be easier to model.

The problem is that the I would like to be able to grant access to all of these entities to the system based on their role types.  In my mind I would like to group them all under a **Member** abstract superclass which could be subclassed by two more abstract classes **Person** and **Company**. 
then the **Person** and **Company** could further be subclassed by more concrete classes like **Employee** or **PropertyManagementCompany** etc..

Where would a **Property** fit in as it is not a person or a company. I guess maybe it would be a **Member**

I have a feeling I am completely missing something as something just doesnt feel right.  So any ideas, or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know php or Zend at all, but you might want to look at the "Party-Role" Pattern.  (Just google, see e.g. ([1](http://www.univdata.com/Portals/9/udm_Publication_Articles_11_05_Models_Patterns.pdf))([2](http://blog.jordanterrell.com/post/Customer-Is-Not-A-Party.aspx))([3](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014))).

In your scenario Person & Organisation are subtypes of Party.  Employee, ServiceVendor, Resident, etc. are all subtypes of Role.  There's a many:many relationship among Party & Role. You can define relationships as required among role subtypes. Assigning permissions should then become easy; each Party gains permissions for each role it is assigned to.

hth.

Comment: I think this is good solution, as here problem mainly in OOP/designing, than in implementing.

Comment: The posts that you linked were great resources, sfinnie, thanks.  Exactly what I need.